# Backup Crashed My Site

Tags: backup

So I tried to backup my site after having some custom programming done to it.

And now the site i gone.  I can't login to the back OR see the front.

Both home and admin login give error:
Internal Server Error

File "/home/thirdcoa/domains/thirdcoastsigns.com/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group

suPHP 0.7.1

Please help!

Comment: Duplicate - known issue. Magento destroys your file/folder permissions without reason. Reset file/folder permissions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/attempted-magento-backup-now-throws-500-internal-server-error-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331207/magento-file-permissions-change-after-system-backup-cause-500-error/18293051#18293051

Comment: Thank you!  That was it exactly.  Not sure why I could not find this . .  .but you just saved my bacon.

Also, if changing php to "664" does not work, try 644 . ... because that was what worked for me.   Don't assume trying one is the trick, try them both.

Comment: Yes, it depends on what the server operator was trying to accomplish with SuExec/SuPHP/WHM. Some servers are totally locked down (usually shared) and others are let have a more open group access. However it works, php files must be able to execute, and 666 is world read/write which in standard security circles is verboten. Why Magento wrongheadedly does what it does is unknown, but indicates programmers running as root/admin when they create it and not taking into account that some of us want to run with increased security.

Comment: Thanks!  I wonder is you can look at what seems to be a related issue for me (forgive me, I'm a bit of a noob . . .)     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337405/residual-problems-from-failed-backup-file-xxxxxx-is-writable-by-group