# Magento 1.9.0.1 Backup and Captcha

Tags: backup, ce-1.9.0.1, captcha

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 with New Installation

and have 2 issues.

1.) After proceeded Backing up and whether checked the "Put store on the maintenance mode while backup creation" or not, Frontend and Backend returns Error 500,

I solved this by using magento-cleanup, and then I can access to both Frontend
and Backend again. But I'm not sure about its side effect.

Could someone give me suggestion or it will be fine?

2.) After the "Enable CAPTCHA on Frontend" was set to YES,
and Forms : selected all items
and Displaying Mode : Always
and then refresh/flush.

The CAPTCHA doesn't display.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Magento 1.9 messes with file permissions which creates major fail under suPHP or WHM/cPanel security settings. This is where your 500 errors come from, NOT maintenance.flag being set. [Magento Backup now throws 500 errors](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/attempted-magento-backup-now-throws-500-internal-server-error-page)

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1.** I just tried doing the backup and restore feature from the Magento Admin Panel.
Magento is putting the store into maintenance mode using the maintenance.flag method. This involves creating a blank file in the sites root directory called "maintenance.flag" once the backup or restore is complete this file will need to be deleted.

**Answer 2.** In the 1.9 [RWD Dev Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide) they say that RWD was not implemented for captcha, I'm not sure why.

It has been disabled by the use of a blank captcha.xml file in the following directery:
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout

If you delete this file it will revert to the one in base/default theme. I can't see a reason why leaving captcha on would cause any problems.

Comment: 1.) so, do I need to delete the maintenance.flag 3 times for fully backup 2.) It's ok to know it from given link. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Once the backup is complete then you can look for the flag and delete it. Also with the Captcha, I have enabled it with in 1.9 and you just need to edit the CSS a little and it works fine. :)

Comment: Using 1.9 RWD 1.) After Backing Up and Error 500 occurs, I can't find the maintenance.flag in the root directory whether show hidden file or not in cPanel. 2.) dear sir, could you tell me where and how to edit CSS for captcha. Thank you very much