# Getting a 500 internal server error :: Back-end >> System >> Tools >> Backups

Tags: admin, permissions, backup, http-error-500

I am trying to take a Backup of My server from the admin panel . Using following options

System >> Tools >> Backups >> System Backup

It gives the popup to mention the name of the file of the backup and gives a loader for some time . Then it gives me a 500 internal error.

The error stays  untill i change the permission of the index.php to 655 .

I request you please provide me the reason behind this error and solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any logs in apache or in Magento?

Comment: Please find the error in my System logs
2014-09-30T10:21:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /home/gangarey/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96

and I dont have a access for the error logs of the apache server.
Sorry for that.

Comment: Is there is no other way to find the issue.

Comment: @Bhandary have you tried giving the permission for the index.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted Magento Backup - now throws 500 Internal server error page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/attempted-magento-backup-now-throws-500-internal-server-error-page) and [Magento file permissions change after system backup - Cause 500 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331207/magento-file-permissions-change-after-system-backup-cause-500-error)