# Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 System Backup Error

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, error, backup

I was using Magento's default backup function when all of a sudden, all pages went 404.

After digging out more information on this error, it was actually caused by permission error. I changed some of the permissions and ran a code(refer to reference post) and got it running again.

While this has been an ongoing error all along, is there an easier/faster way to execute system backup?

Currently, I am using phpmyadmin and cPanel as manual backup.

Reference: 
[Attempted Magento Backup - now throws 500 Internal server error page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/attempted-magento-backup-now-throws-500-internal-server-error-page)

Comment: always use external backup, built in cPanel

Comment: You can't get more basic and quicker than mysqldump and tar -xzf based scripts from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's built-in backup is not only inefficient but it always attempt to reset the file permissions to insecure permissions like 666 and 777 without taking into account that some servers do not need such insecure permissions to run properly. This exact same issue plagued Magento Connect Manager as well.

I highly recommend that you use a backup system which is external to the application level for the best efficiency and stability. cPanel's Full Backup is a good option but you may need to run it manually. You may also want to consider a third-party backup solution like CodeGuard which can take backups of your files and database at a fixed interval and store it remotely.