# 404 page for magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to use magento connect to install a plugin. I am receiving a 404 page when i try to open it.

I tried to

```
1] delete the files from var/cache

2] check if the following values on database are correct according to those instructions:

UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT
```

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Did you make sure to logout from the Magento Admin Panel again, and log in again? Or are you referring to that the Magento Connect application itself can not be found? If it is the last, do you have a "downloader" folder in your Magento root?

Comment: I tried to logout and login again. I am referring to the magento connect application itself. I have the downloader folder.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have an issue with the webserver configuration. Normally when you access the Magento Connect app, the URL is like `http://MAGENTO/downloader/index.php`. What happens if you add `/index.php` at the end, so `http://MAGENTO/downloader/index.php`?

Comment: I get 404 for both ways.

Comment: Ok, so when there is actually a file /downloader/index.php present, and it gives you a 404 error, apparently something in the webserver is stopping you from accessing it.

Comment: One more question, is the 404-error you get a Magento 404-error or a 404-error from your webserver (Apache, Nginx, something similar)?

Comment: Is magento 404 page

Comment: Then I think something is wrong with either your webserver configuration, or your htaccess-file. Make sure the /downloader/ folder contains a htaccess-file as well. Also, check the htaccess-file of your Magento root to see if there is any rule there that mentions the keyword "downloader".

Comment: My root .htaccess does not have the word downloader inside. Also my /downloader .htaccess seems fine <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE
    RemoveOutputFilter GZIP

</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.(cfg|ini|xml)$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

Comment: Then this is definitely related to your webserver configuration: When you request any PHP file from a subfolder, the webserver should simply call upon that subfolders PHP file. Instead, this is ignore in your configuration, and the main Magento index.php is called instead. Somewhere in your webserver configuration there's something denied here. If you have set this up yourself, you might dive into the VirtualHost configuration. If your hosting provider has set this up for you, they need to solve this.

Comment: didnt works. i have try every person comment, nothing get it

Answer (score 6):

Alex ,
Try to provide the Permission

Change permission of Directory /downloader/ set to 755 and file /downloader/index.php set to 644. This method works for me .

Did you Upgraded Magento ?

Comment: Hello AJ, i am using magento 1.5. I didn't upgrade it. My permissions are allready setup like that.

Comment: Alex, Go to the below Link & download magento1.5 & then take downloader folder only replace to your domain downloader folder it will resolve your Problem  https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/  Hope This help you it works for me

Comment: I tried that but still the same.

Comment: @MagentoAJ I don't think the files are corrupt or anything. I think something is preventing the webserver from executing this /downloader/index.php in the first place, most likely due to some specific RewriteEngine configuration.

Comment: Did you tried to replace the downloader folder its works for me many times

Comment: Thanks for the info but unfortunately that didn't work. I tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you any .htaccess file in downloader folder? If yes, then download that as a backup and delete that from folder. Refresh the cache and delete the previous session. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Tried not working

Answer (score 3):

Some host are know to keep having issue with default landing page as index.php
Try this on your url below:

```
http://yourdomain.com/downloader/index.php?return=http://yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/
```

Kindly replace your `yourdomain.com` with the correct domain of yours.

I hope this help. Dont forget to mark this as correct if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this same issue and it was related to file/folder permissions--specifically *index.php* in the *downloader* folder. However, there could be other permissions causing the issue in your case.

I would suggest downloading and running the [Magento Cleanup Tool](https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento) by downloading the *magento-cleanup.php* file to the root of your server and pointing your browser to: http://www.[YOURDOMAIN].com/magento-cleanup.php

You should get several status updates on the screen to confirm completion of the "cleanup."

Comment: If the link to this cleanup tool goes down (as it did on the Magento site),  the contents of the file have been pasted into this answer:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7462/24331

Answer (score 1):

I once encountered this issue and I had mine solved thru the folder's htaccess. 
    *order allow,deny
    deny from all*
Simply add your ip address.
    *Allow from 123.456.78.90 #your IP*

Aside from checking or adding your ip address on your htaccess file, make sure you have the correct folder and file permission.
downloader 755
downloader/index.php 644

Answer (score 1):

Check permission of `/downloader/` folder if permission is not `755` then set it to `755` and check permission of `/downloader/index.php` file and set to `644`.

If this not work then backup your downloader folder and download fresh magento setup and upload only downloader folder into your root directory.

Hope that will work for you, it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

if you want immediate & better solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento will put a "deny from all" in the .htaccess file located in the downloader directory.

Simply change this to "allow from all" and it should work.

..or putting an allow from x.x.x.x (where x.x.x.x is your IP address) will allow access. If you wish to lock down the downloader directory (I highly recommend it) then change the "allow from all" to "allow from x.x.x.x and put a "deny from all" on the next line.